# 3D printer G-code problem

Tags: print-quality, 3d-design, diy-3d-printer, electronics

[image: Photo of DIY printer]

[image: Screenshot of Edit settings dialog]

I am currently doing a DIY 3D printer using RAMPS1.4 and it works as I have tested all X, Y and Z axis including the extruder extruding filament. I have jogged all the axis using Pronterface Software. I am printing a simple solid cube (20 mm x 20 mm x 20 mm) and the cube G-code I generated from Slic3r is uploaded on google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JqmhIk2ULWwMpn9wOWrucyA2CcaFFkLO/view?usp=sharing).

The problem is when it is printing for like 5 seconds, the X- and Y-axis suddenly moves so much to the ends of the beams and I am unsure why, I believe is the G-code problem. I would really appreciate if anyone can give me some advice on this and what went wrong. I am so close to printing my first cube.

I run G-code from Slic3r on the Pronterface software. The video on this problem is uploaded google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xy7j9eECDt4G1yaNsspTQWKhqa3kE73z/view?usp=sharing), can just view without download. As you can see at the end of the video, the axis can move from one end to the other end and the beam is so long, how is it even possible? I have to switch off the power at the end to prevent damage to wheels.

Comment: @Greenonline, hi, do you know what went wrong? I believe is the g0code, right? I can see you have a lot of experience on this. I just started a week ago haha buiding it from scratch :)

Comment: @Greenonline, I have tested it with CNC ramp using arduino uno to skecth out some 2d skecth using a pen, not a problem with the hardware at all. What a weird problem haha.

Comment: @Greenonline, yes, i tried also to put it center. But after some time of printing 10seconds, the x and y axis just miraculously moves out of bound to the edge of the beams and almost damage my wheels, so i just turn off the mains switch emergency

Comment: @Greenonline, hi, I have uploaded a video link of my problem in my post :(, feels dissapointed

Comment: The center of the build plate is rarely the origin, in 99 % it is a corner (unless it is a Delta, a MakerBot or an Ultimaker and some rare other brand).

Comment: @Oscar, one thing I notice, is that when I try to press the center red button (home button), the axis moves out of bound and almost damage the wheels too and I have to switch off the power suppy :)

Comment: There is too much wrong with this build, I don't know where to start. First fix your endstops and homing, next fix your slicer settings. Depending on the endstop positions the origin is defined through your firmware, so fix firmware. Great first attempt, ingenious ways to fix parts,  a true tinkerer!